# Permission denied when installing go mockgen

Tags: go

I am trying to install the mockgen package on go, but I keep receiving a permission denied without knowing why:

```
go install github.com/golang/mock/mockgen@v1.6.0
```

Output:

> go install github.com/golang/mock/mockgen: copying /tmp/go-build3889221292/b001/exe/a.out: open /home/nocnoc/go/bin/mockgen: permission denied

I have tried using sudo or executing it as root, but I receive this error

> sudo: go: command not found

My GOROOT is /usr/local/go and GOPATH is in my home directory. GO1111MODULE is also on.

How can I fix it? Everything else seems to run fine, and only mockgen seems to fail to install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the permissions and owners of directories *~/go* and *~/go/bin*. It was solved by using the `chown` command to change the owner of those two directories from root to my user:

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 root   root       4096 Aug 11  2020  go
```

to

```
drwxrwxr-x 10 nocnoc nocnoc     4096 Aug 11  2020  go
```

The permissions and owners of *~/go/bin* are the same as those for the directory above.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a Linux expert, but try running:

```sh
sudo su
go install github.com/golang/mock/mockgen@v1.6.0
```

Comment: Running that command as root returns the error that "Command 'go' not found"